# vim: regex search/replace "g" flag behavior inverted

Tags: search, vim

When I issue an ex command in the vim command line, e.g. `:% s/^I/    /g` (replacing all tabs in file with spaces -- the `^I` is not carat-capital-i, it's the tab character entered by typing <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+i</kbd>), I end up with only the replacement operation affecting the first match within the lines specified.

Then on a hunch what I tried the command without the `g` flag, `:% s/^I/    /`

This worked and did the job on all the tabs.

This is backwards!

Why?

I have a ludicrously huge `.vimrc`, it is 1199 lines as of today, so it's pretty certain that something in it or in the plugins I use is causing this behavior. However, especially now that I have found the way to get the global flag working again, I am certainly not looking to sacrifice any of the plugins or even really attempt to do some kind of manual binary search hunting to blindly narrow down the cause of this, as that would take too long.

Comment: Check if `gdefault` is set in your `.vimrc`

Comment: It looks like you came across this question trying to convert tabs to spaces in your file. I find it's simpler to do this using `:let tabstop="    "` and `:retab`

Comment: That's the dumbest and laziest question I've seen in quite some time. *You* added `gdefault` to *your* vimrc without care and *you* ask others to find *your* mistake for *you* without even posting *your* vimrc. Did you ever learn what responsibility is?

Comment: well i had completely forgotten about it though. Yes, it's quite lazy of me to post this, I agree. However now that this question exists it helps others who are in the same situation find more results when they google these keywords. Not the end of the world.

Comment: Perfectly valid question. vim's documentation is not always crystal clear and I too tend to ask google no less often then the docs whenever it behaves in some strange and unpredicted way. And I had to do binary search through `.vimrc` many times too. Yet it doesn't stop me from loving vim :)

Comment: That's a valid question, yes. But one to ask oneself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the 'gdefault' option is on, this flag is on by default and the [g]
>   argument switches it off.

**Update:**

The 'Feng shui' way to get to this line in the docs is `:h :s`, then `CTRL-]` on "`:s_flags`"

Comment: Yep, this was set in my vimrc. I then forgot that it existed AND that I had set it.

Comment: I think you meant `<c-]>` not `<c-^>`